# How to Define Object's __str__ in a Python C++ Extension

Tags: python, c++

Implementing a `__str__` function in C. This is my function definition:

```
static PyObject *
Foo_str(FooObject *self)
{
    return PyUnicode_FromFormat("bar");
}
```

And the export:

```
static PyMethodDef Foo_methods[] = {
    { "__str__", reinterpret_cast<PyCFunction>(Foo_str), METH_VARARGS, "Pretty print" },
    { NULL }  /* sentinel */
};
```

Now, in Python, `print(str(myobj))` does not work while `print(myobj.__str__())` does. How do I implement my own type casting and Python function overriding in a C/C++ extension?

Comment: Using C++ you'd be using a class for it, you could just make a `toString` method for it to do `obj.toString()`. But in C, you can make a toString function that takes the struct-type as a parameter, and then tell it what to do with it

Comment: I'm not a Python expert, but knowing what I know of C++ I'd say that 9 out of 10 times a `reinterpret_cast` is an attempt to force the wrong thing to work, and so is highly suspect.

Comment: Is this pybind11? Or you are trying to write Python modules on your own?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I'm writing a custom extension, not pybind11 nor SWIG.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, there is a special method when registering the class:

```
foo_type.tp_str = Foo_str;
```

also, the function `self` argument is of type `PyObject`.